# Neo4J Error in (shortest) paths

Tags: neo4j, path, shortest

[image]
I am doing the coursera coursework for NEO4J at an institution.

I note that the examples on paths and lengths and shorest path all show on my machine different results to that in the course notes /lectures.

I am using 3.0.6. Are there bugs? I note that it seems to disregard direction of edge. Could it be some setting that I need to set?

Thanks in advance

LOAD

```
 CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/coursera/data/test.csv" AS line
   MERGE (n:MyNode {Name:line.Source})
   MERGE (m:MyNode {Name:line.Target})
   MERGE (n) -[:TO {dist:line.distance}]-> (m)

   match p=(a)-[:TO*]-(c)
   where a.Name='H' and c.Name='P'
   return p limit 1
```

Comment: Could you please provide data set and queries which you are using?

Comment: Source Target distance
A C 3
B D 5
C J 2
D E 4
E G 4
F A 5
G D 1
H J 5
L E 8
J F 7
D C 3
A L 6
C B 7
G P 4

Comment: LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///coursera/data/test.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:MyNode {Name:line.Source})
MERGE (m:MyNode {Name:line.Target})
MERGE (n) -[:TO {dist:line.distance}]-> (m)

Comment: match p=(a)-[:TO*]-(c)
where a.Name='H' and c.Name='P'
return p limit 1

Comment: Don't see how it can go thru C based on direction of graph.

Comment: In any event I get different result to course lecture, so I am a little confused

Comment: I think your cypher is getting cut off. Please edit your description and add it there instead of in the comments, formatting so it's easily readable, thanks

Comment: LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/coursera/data/test.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:MyNode {Name:line.Source})
MERGE (m:MyNode {Name:line.Target})
MERGE (n) -[:TO {dist:line.distance}]-> (m)

match p=(a)-[:TO*]-(c)
where a.Name='H' and c.Name='P'
return p limit 1

Comment: see main box, not so handy with this I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're using:

```
match p=(a)-[:TO*]-(c)
where a.Name='H' and c.Name='P'
return p limit 1
```

The match itself finds one possible path between the two given nodes using that pattern. It makes no guarantees about distance or ordering (I ran this on mine and it returned a fairly convoluted path, far from from shortest distance). If the course notes said that this is a shortest path query, then it's wrong.

In neo4j, the only way to enforce and guarantee shortest path is with the shortestPath() function, or allShortestPaths(). For example:

```
match p= shortestPath((a)-[:TO*]-(c))
where a.Name='H' and c.Name='P'
return p limit 1
```

EDIT

As you noted, the query you're using is undirected, so it will traverse any relationship it finds regardless of direction to find a path. There is a significant difference between matching on an undirected relationship pattern vs a directed relationship pattern. You can try running the query with a directed relationship and see the difference.

```
match p= shortestPath((a)-[:TO*]->(c))
where a.Name='H' and c.Name='P'
return p limit 1
```

Comment: Ok, that had not escaped me, but I was a bit surprised how it went against the direction of C which was outward and not inward. Even with the query you have above which i have also tried. I am just missing something. I take your point on the above though.

Comment: by ordering you mean whether in or out nodes. that is not so evident, means we can all get different results with limit is 1

Comment: I added a note on that, there is a difference between matching on a directed vs an undirected relationship, so make sure you're using the right one.

Comment: Replying to your ordering question, that's correct. Without shortestPath() (or a similarly-behaving procedure, such as the dijkstra procedure in the APOC procedures library), there are no ordering guarantees unless a) there is only one result, so ordering won't matter OR b) you add an ORDER BY clause with precise enough ordering criteria.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any additional related questions here (I also recommend rereading the Cypher documentation regarding relationships, both directed and undirected). Otherwise, please accept this answer.